# Generic Object type in typescript

Tags: typescript, object, types

In typescript is there any way to assign a variable a generic object type.
Here's what I mean by 'generic Object type'

```
let myVariable: GenericObject = 1 // Should throw an error
                              = 'abc' // Should throw an error
                              = {} // OK
                              = {name: 'qwerty'} //OK
```

i.e. It should only allow javascript objects to be assigned to the variable and no other type of data(number, string, boolean)

Answer (score 116):

Sure thing:

```
type GenericObject = { [key: string]: any };

let myVariable1: GenericObject = 1; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'
let myVariable2: GenericObject = 'abc'; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'
let myVariable3: GenericObject = {} // OK
let myVariable4: GenericObject = {name: 'qwerty'} //OK
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20GenericObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20myVariable1%3A%20GenericObject%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D'%0Alet%20myVariable2%3A%20GenericObject%20%3D%20'abc'%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%20%7D'%0Alet%20myVariable3%3A%20GenericObject%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20OK%0Alet%20myVariable4%3A%20GenericObject%20%3D%20%7Bname%3A%20'qwerty'%7D%20%2F%2FOK))

Comment: At least on TS 4.1.3 I get error `TS2345: Argument of type 'GenericObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.` when I try to pass it to `new Proxy()`. 
Any ideas?

Comment: @Romasato when i try that in the ts playground (ts 4.1.2) it works well, can you reproduce it there?

Comment: GenericObject here is the same as Record<string, any>

You can also use Record<string, unknown> if you don't use any.

Answer (score 84):

Typescript 2.1+ also has has a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt), `Record<K, T>`, you can use instead of making your own definition

```
const myObj: Record<string, any>;
```

I like to use the style described in top answer when I can give a meaningful name to `key` but if it's not really as obvious or necessary `Record` is a great option.

Answer (score 5):

As of TypeScript 3.0+ this is the type-safe answer:

```js
type GenericObject = Record<string, unknown>;
```

And since you'll be getting type protection, you need to do a type check before using a property of the object:

```js
const obj: GenericObject = {
  someFn: () => 'string return';
}

if (typeof obj.someFn === 'function') {
  obj.someFn();
}
```

TypeScript will not complain about `any` of course but it is technically not the "generic object type".

**More info on the differences between `any` and `unknown`**:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type
- https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-unknown-vs-any/

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

From ESLint hint:

- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `object`.

So the alternative is:

```
type GenericObject = object;
```

Or just use `object` directly where its needed. Note that letter casing is crucial since the `Object` type signifies "any non-nullish value" and might be discouraged.

---

**Bonus:**

This solution: `type GenericObject = { [key: string]: unknown };` might not be the best option if you have a class data structure as it might lead to the errors:

> Argument of type 'DummyClass' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'GenericObject'.
>
> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type
> 'DummyClass'

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a tangent since I haven't found a similar answer elsewhere, from @JaredMcAteer here, using `record` helped me with mixing enums + objects.

```
enum FOO_ENUM {
  BAR = 'BAZ';
}

type FOO_OBJECT_TYPE = { ... };

const BIZ_OBJECT: Record<FOO_ENUM, FOO_OBJECT_TYPE> = {
  [FOO_ENUM.BAR]: { ... }
}
```

Where before I was typing `BIZ_OBJECT` as
`BIZ_OBJECT: {[type: string]: FOO_OBJECT}`
which allowed something like `BIZ_OBJECT.asd`, now only a key from `FOO_ENUM` can be used, e.g.

- `BIZ_OBJECT.BAZ // { ... }`
- `BIZ_OBJECT.asd // Property 'asd' does not exist on type ...`
- `BIZ_OBJECT[FOO_ENUM.BAR] // { ... }`
- `BIZ_OBJECT[FOO_ENUM.asd] // Property 'asd' does not ...`
- `BIZ_OBJECT[FOO_ENUM['asd']] // ! not caught !`

Comment: Besides the point, but I recommend naming your type like `FooObjectType`, and enum like `FooEnum`. Personally I find type name with `ALL_CAPS` too noisy.

Answer (score -1):

As of TypeScript 2.2 you can use

```
let myVariable: object;
```

Edit: Here's an example:

```
let myVariable: object = { fun: 1 };
```

Comment: this does not work eg: `const me: object = {}; me.fun = 1` Will throw an error. `Property 'fun' does not exist on type 'object'.`

Comment: But you can do `let myVariable: object = { fun: 1 };` which is what the OP asked.

Comment: The built-in `object` type also doesn't define an index signature, so it's not a very good placeholder for generic objects, unfortunately.

Comment: @BillBarnes nobody creates an object to leave it empty, OP is showing an empty object on line 3 therefore this is NOT what OP asked.

Comment: Don't use `object` for this. It exists for a different reason : to remove primitives : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y5hhzuQjCA