# Typescript: Function parameter in Class Method has narrower parameter than in the parent class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, callback

I have two typescript classes. One extends the other:

```
type NamedObject = {
    name: string;
}

class AnyObjectManager {
    objectList = [];
    getAnyObject = (matches: (o: object) => boolean) => {
        for (const o of this.objectList) {
            if (matches(o)) {
                return o;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class NamedObjectManager extends AnyObjectManager {
    getObjectNamedTim = () => {
        return this.getAnyObject(this.objectIsNamedTim)
    }
    objectIsNamedTim = (namedObject: NamedObject) => {
        return namedObject.name === 'Tim';
    }
}
```

In the method NamedObjectManager.getObjectNamedTim, typescript shows an error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(namedObject: NamedObject) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(o: object) => boolean'.   
>   Types of parameters 'namedObject' and 'o' are incompatible.     
>   Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'NamedObject'.

Now, I know that NamedObjectManager will only manage NamedObjects. Assume that functions like addObject make sure that only NamedObjects will be here. So, how can I tell typescript that all objects managed by NamedObjectManager will be NamedObjects, and that we can safely assume this in methods we inherit from the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) and manage objects in "type safe" way:

```
class AnyObjectManager<T> {
    objectList: T[] = [];
    getAnyObject = (matches: (o: T) => boolean) => {
        for (const o of this.objectList) {
            if (matches(o)) {
                return o;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class NamedObjectManager extends AnyObjectManager<NamedObject> {
    getObjectNamedTim = () => {
        return this.getAnyObject(this.objectIsNamedTim)
    }
    objectIsNamedTim = (namedObject: NamedObject) => {
        return namedObject.name === 'Tim';
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgEwPICMBWEDGwoC8UA3gLABQUUAdohAFxQDOwATgJbUDmA3BQL4UKOADZwmTKAEFqIDNjwBZOLS4RWAHgAqAPhIUqAeyy5gAGXYtGWgNoBdQlHt9KUNcBlyTeRwAoEcMA4ABYQTIy+htYAlIR66IaGIhAqsQR6ZK5UAGaGrFC+OIbULFCGZdlQwMGWAHTGCuaWwLGZVO1Q7JX+gSFhkdGtBh3trBDAAK6s1GUuI1CCWQvDVGOT0zQTIiJzy+SLwmISsHRo3sDKqupQEAAewBDUyJKe8qaXcGqa8EhnjRnDdxvPA-FBadgIPxpAFLNZTGbVOruV7nXyIpj1c4ASSYoOQ4IQ0WGiyM2NxpwJflov2BwEYeNp0P0sPG8Jop1ptWp0AIvKgAHICfzdot+EA)

---

Not related, `getAnyObject` can be simplified to:

```
getAnyObject = (matches: (o: T) => boolean) => this.objectList.find(matches) || null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there some way to only allow Objects as T (not strings, numbers etc)? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641370/generic-object-type-in-typescript) does not seem to have the solution, and the typescript generics doc only explains how to expect specific properties on T.

Comment: @KWeiss sure: `AnyObjectManager<T extends object>` More info here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object