# How do I add a generic object as return type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am writing a function in typescript which will take an a parameter of type Request and then return an object whose structure is variable. The function that i have written is this:

```
export async function getFormData<T>(req: Request): Promise<T> {
  let data = {} as T
  const formdata = await req.formData();
  formdata.forEach((value, key) => {
    data[key] = value; // <- This line gives the error
  });
  return data;
}
```

My reasoning is that when i run the function getFormData I'd run it like
`const res = await getFormData<myInterface>(req);`
So that way res would have the proper type of `myInterface`. But Typescript keep giving me the error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'
```

TL;DR: How do i write a function which will return an object of type that will be specified when i call the function

This([Generic Object type in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641370/generic-object-type-in-typescript)) question kinda solves the issue, but then i get everything as 'any' type

Comment: use `T extends something`...

Comment: also zod can be your friend here

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without unrelated problems; Your `data` variable is undefined and you are trying to set its properties, which will result in a runtime error. Unless you're asking about that, please fix it. ② `Request` has no idea that `formData()` will return values of type `T` and indeed there is no such guarantee. If you are willing to just *assert* that it works, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3KY1m) should be the most straightforward. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz the `data` variable is just instantiated so then i can modify it in `forEach`. I have edited the code to make it more clear what i'm trying to do. Also your approach works. Can you please explain why? I am very new to TypeScript so assume very little knowledge

Comment: I will write up an answer when I give it a chance, but please [edit] your code to be `let data = {}` in some form (maybe `let data = {} as T`?) for the reason I explained above, you can't set properties of `undefined`. I'd be happy to make the edit myself if you are okay with it.

Comment: @jcalz edited the code as requested. added `let data = {} as T` which does not give more errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) represents a set of key-value pairs, where the keys are some unknown `string`s and the values are some unknown `FormDataEntryValue` which is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c5db0ac0ef57d75ef277a4af6b473e5637d95ca0/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L28174) as [either](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) a `string` or a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).  There is absolutely no guarantee that when you assemble those into an object, that this object will match your `T` type.  The compiler errors are basically warning you that it cannot safely assign the `value` to `data[key]` because it knows neither that `key` is a valid key of `T` nor that `value` would be an appropriate value for that key if it does exist on `T`.

Indeed, with a call signature like `<T>(req: Request) => Promise<T>` it is *impossible* to implement safely. Someone could call both `getFormData<MyInterface>(req)` and `getFormData<AnotherInferface>(req)` with the *same* `req` variable.  According to the call signature, the first call would return a `Promise<MyInterface>` and the second would return a `Promise<AnotherInterface>`. But that can't happen; at runtime those are both just `getFormData(req)`.  At most one of those calls can be correct.

So, if you really want to keep the call signature like this, you are essentially relying on the caller to know via some out-of-band source of information which `T` to specify for a given `req`.  And that the caller is basically just *asserting* the correctness of that `T`.

And therefore, you might as well use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside the body of `getFormData()`. Type assertions are not type safe, but they are one way to convey such out-of-band type information to the compiler.  Here's one approach:

```
async function getFormData<T>(req: Request): Promise<T> {
    let data: Record<string, FormDataEntryValue> = {};
    (await req.formData()).forEach((value, key) => {
        data[key] = value;
    });
    return data as T;
}
```

The only safe thing to make `data` is a `Record<string, FormDataEntryValue>` (using the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) utility type).  That's a type with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that means "`data` might have any `string` key whatsoever, and all its properties are of type `FormDataEntryValue`."  Once you make that change, the code before `return` compiles without error... after all, it is safe to assign a `FormDataEntryValue` to a property of type `FormDataEntryValue`.

The `return` line now has the type assertion `return data as T;`.  This is the part where you tell the compiler that whatever `T` the caller has specified is going to match the type of `data`.  Again, this is not type safe... or at least you are shifting the burden of type safety from the compiler to yourself.  If it turns out that someone calls `getFormData<TheWrongInterface>(req)` in their code, there will likely be problems at runtime, because the compiler just believes that `data` will be of type `TheWrongInterface`.  Any negative consequences of that mistaken belief cannot be blamed on the compiler, which *tried* to warn you that there was a problem until you asserted it into compliance.

So there you go.  That code compiles without error, and it *may* behave well at runtime assuming the callers know the actual shape of the returned data, and that they specify it correctly when calling.  Or it may blow up at runtime. It is out of scope for the question as asked to figure out which one is more likely to happen, and how to make things safer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFNkBi6ATgLYAiwywAPACoB8AFMbgI4BcMASuwriGQBKLgAVi6UqhC56DGAG8AUDFUwANvhgATKsC68oJbTUHFUEbABoYRMpWoBRCMmJgAasHX95AXkUAvgDcKmpMwADuwKjIMKxsAHRwJBR6TEJCSSSOwFAAFkxMAG5e-DYA1rhgQjC+8spqjTp6ANqVYAC6tTAl3rghjQFCA2qsyAjEWLrUMKAwdCEBQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation it makes a lot of things clear and now I understand why typescript was yelling at me. I know this is beyond the scope of the question but you said " with a call signature like <T>(req: Request) => Promise<T> it is impossible to implement safely" I want to know if there is a different way to achieve the same thing but is also safer? You dont have to write a whole explanation to it, just some resources will be much appreciated.